# How Do I Fade & Drop In A Div Element

Tags: jquery

I have a div called `#login_wrap` which looks a bit like an speech bubble. I need this div to fade in and drop into place with jQuery.

The effect I am trying to describe would be very much like the Fade In Down effect under [Fading entrances by Dan Eden](http://daneden.me/animate/#cta). I would use his CSS version but it doesn't seem to be working for me and I don't think its fully browser compatible anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working demo (jsBin)](http://jsbin.com/usulag/edit#javascript,html,live)**

CSS:

```
#element{
    display:none;
    margin-top:-15px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

jQ:

```
$('#element').css({display:'block'}).animate({marginTop:'0px', opacity:'1'},500);
```

Comment: @Dan :) I've seen your name under the Question, and seen all the answers... and said: let's help my old friend! Thanks Dan, see ya around

Comment: haha cheers man! :)

just getting one problem, I have a shadow image placed in a div called shadow_div which is directly underneath the div that im animating. However the shadow seems to be moving with the box, is there a way I can fix the shadow div's position so it doesn't move and only animate the login_area div?

Comment: May you please setup a jsFiddle? (I think you should set the animations to the element that has the shadow! As if I get it right,  it's actually the PARENT element of your 'element')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5744/discussion-between-dan-farrell-and-roxon)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition){
jQuery('#login_wrap').fadeOut("normal",function(){

// to do something
});
}else{
jQuery('#login_wrap').fadeIn("normal",function(){
// to do something
});
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this code out at the moment but I believe it would be

```
$('#login_wrap').show("drop", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

You are going to need to use the jquery ui library for the above however: http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

If you do not want to use it than you can just simply fade in

```
$('login_wrap').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it what you mean is "fadeInDown"
If that's the case, how about this (check what's in the onclick of the input button):

```
<html>
  <div id="login_wrap" style="position: absolute; border: 3px solid black; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;">
   Watch This! (your login_wrap stuff)
  </div>
  <input type="button" onclick="$('div').css('opacity', 0).css('top', -20); $('#login_wrap').animate({top: '20', opacity: 1});" value="Animate" style="float: right;"/>
</html>
```

In other words:
First I'm setting the css values (using `.css()`) to make login_wrap higher and invisible
Second I'm using `.animate({top: '20', opacity: 1})` to move the div down and make it visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, which acts as **FadeIn Down** by **+50px**

```
<button id="top">FadeInDown</button>
<div class="block"></div>


$("#top").click(function(){
  $(".block").removeAttr("style").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});
```